# hide the already selected value from the dropdown list

Tags: php, cakephp

i am having a dropdown in my page and when i select a option from it and submit it again the same option appears in dropdwon

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('dealer_id1',array('label'=>false,'class'=>'custom-select','options' =>$dealerlist,'empty' => '','required'));  ?>
```

What should i do to hide once selected option from drop down list?

Comment: Remove selected option from `$dealerlist` array..

Comment: you have to manually remove it from `$dealerlist`